# API return answer is 'queued'. What does this mean?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, bulk-delete

We are using the API delete contacts. However we cannot se that the delete contacts call have had any impact, actually none. Our return answer for every call is 'queued' but what does this mean? How long does it take to have the calls executed? Smaller batches gives the same result